# QGraphicsScene/View Scale Understanding

Tags: c++, qt

I'm lost with understanding the scale value of QGraphicsScene/View.

Here is how I'm placing my targets in the scene.

```
QPointF Mainwindow::pointLocation(double bearing, double range){
    int offset = 90; //used to offset Cartesian system
    double centerX = baseSceneSize/2;//push my center location out to halfway point
    double centerY = baseSceneSize/2;
    double newX = centerX + qCos(qDegreesToRadians(bearing - offset)) * range;
    double newY = centerY + qSin(qDegreesToRadians(bearing - offset)) * range;
    QPointF newPoint = QPointF(newX, newY);
    return newPoint;

}
```

So each target has a bearing and range. As long as I don't scale, or zoom, the scene, these values work sufficiently.  My problem is that I need to implement the zooming.

Here's where things go wrong:

I have a target at Bearing 270, Range 10.

When the app runs, and my vertical slider is at a value of zero, I can see this target in my view. I should not.  I need for this target to only come into view when the slider has gotten to a value of 10.  Just think each position value on the slider equates to 1 nautical mile. So if a target is at 10 NMs it should only be visible once the slider is >= 10.

here is how I'm doing the zooming:

```
void MainWindow:: on_PlotSlider_sliderMoved(int position){
    const qreal factor = 1.01;
    viewScaleValue = qPow(factor, -position);//-position to invert the scale
    QMatrix matrix;
    matrix.scale(viewScaleValue, viewScaleValue);
    view->setMatrix(matrix);
}
```

I've tried making the View bigger, the Scene bigger, but nothing is having the proper effect.

Here is my Scene setup:

```
view = ui->GraphicsView;
scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
int baseSize = 355;
scene->setSceneRect(0,0,baseSize,baseSize);
baseSceneSize = scene->sceneRect().width();
view->setScene(scene);
```

How do I take the range of my target and push it out into the scene so that it lines up with the slider value?

Comment: I think that the idea of a "base" scene size is unnecessary. Use whatever units make sense, e.g. nautical miles, as your scene units, and assume the position of your vessel to be at the origin of the coordinate system. Then place the targets at the coordinates of `QPoint(range*cos(bearing), range*sin(bearing)`. The zoom selects a mapping between the scene and the view such that a given number of miles fits in the view. The scene will take care of the rest.

Comment: the base scene size was to ensure that I was placing the objects in the center of the view before offsetting for the range and bearing conversion. Plus it was an element of testing used to try and see what would change the unit measurement of the scene.

how do I "use whatever units, as my scene units"?

Comment: Just to clarify, the 355 baseSize comes from the actual dimensions of the QGraphicsView in my UI.

If I don't 
    centerX = baseSceneSize/2;

then the items are created based off the upper left of the view, not the center.

Comment: The scene and the view are completely different beasts. The scene should be designed as is convenient for you when you add items to it. For a vessel radar style image, I'd think that vessel at 0,0 makes it easiest, and the units are nautical miles. To display a range of 10NM on the view, you center the scene in the view, and scale view/scene at min(viewHeight/20.0, viewWidth/20.0), were 20.0 is 10NM left/right/top/down. All of this is really, really simple - you're complicating things otherwise.

Comment: I understand I may have overcomplicated things, hence why I started with "I'm lost"

I see how "(viewHeight/20.0, viewWidth/20.0)" makes sense, but I don't see how to implement it I what I have.

Comment: Do I scale the view or the scene?

Comment: The view. The scene has fixed units - e.g. nautical miles.

Comment: how do I set the scene units?

Comment: It is a no-op. You don't set them at all. You just use them. As long as you're consistent, you've "set" them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`QGraphicsView::fitInView` is everything you need to select the displayed range and center the view.

Here's how you might do it. It's a complete example.

[image: screenshot of the example]

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/scene-radar-40680065
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <random>
```

First, let's obtain random target positions. The scene is scaled in e.g. Nautical Miles: thus any coordinate in the scene is meant to be in these units. This is only a convention: the scene otherwise doesn't care, nor does the view. The reference point is at 0,0: all ranges/bearings are relative to the origin.

```
QPointF randomPosition() {
    static std::random_device dev;
    static std::default_random_engine eng(dev());
    static std::uniform_real_distribution<double> posDis(-100., 100.); // NM
    return {posDis(eng), posDis(eng)};
}
```

Then, to aid in turning groups of scene items on and off (e.g. graticules), it helps to have an empty parent item for them:

```
class EmptyItem : public QGraphicsItem {
public:
    QRectF boundingRect() const override { return QRectF(); }
    void paint(QPainter *, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *, QWidget *) override {}
};
```

A scene manager sets up the display. The empty items act as item collections and they can be easily made hidden/visible without having to modify child items. They also enforce the relative Z-order of their children.

```
class SceneManager : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(bool microGraticuleVisible READ microGraticuleVisible WRITE setMicroGraticuleVisible)
    QGraphicsScene m_scene;
    QPen m_targetPen{Qt::green, 1};
    EmptyItem m_target, m_center, m_macroGraticule, m_microGraticule;
```

An event filter can be installed on the view to signal when the view has been resized. This can be used to keep the view centered in spite of resizing:

```
    bool eventFilter(QObject *watched, QEvent *event) override {
        if (event->type() == QEvent::Resize 
                && qobject_cast<QGraphicsView*>(watched))
            emit viewResized();
        return QObject::eventFilter(watched, event);
    }
```

Scene has the following Z-order: center cross, macro- and micro-graticule, then the targets are on top.

```
public:
    SceneManager() {
        m_scene.addItem(&m_center);
        m_scene.addItem(&m_macroGraticule);
        m_scene.addItem(&m_microGraticule);
        m_scene.addItem(&m_target);
        m_targetPen.setCosmetic(true);
        addGraticules();
    }
```

We can monitor a graphics view for resizing; we also expose the visibility of the micro graticule.

```
    void monitor(QGraphicsView *view) { view->installEventFilter(this); }
    QGraphicsScene * scene() { return &m_scene; }
    Q_SLOT void setMicroGraticuleVisible(bool vis) { m_microGraticule.setVisible(vis); }
    bool microGraticuleVisible() const { return m_microGraticule.isVisible(); }
    Q_SIGNAL void viewResized();
```

Targets can be randomly generated. A target has a fixed size in view coordinates. Its position, though, is subject to any scene-to-view transformations.

The pens for targets and graticules are cosmetic pens: their width is given in the view device units (pixels), not scene units.

```
    void newTargets(int count = 200) {
        qDeleteAll(m_target.childItems());
        for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
            auto target = new QGraphicsEllipseItem(-1.5, -1.5, 3., 3., &m_target);
            target->setPos(randomPosition());
            target->setPen(m_targetPen);
            target->setBrush(m_targetPen.color());
            target->setFlags(QGraphicsItem::ItemIgnoresTransformations);
        }
    }
```

The graticules are concentric circles centered at the origin (range reference point) and a cross at the origin. The origin cross has fixed size in view units - this is indicated by the `ItemIgnoresTransformations` flag.

```
   void addGraticules() {
        QPen pen{Qt::white, 1};
        pen.setCosmetic(true);
        auto center = {QLineF{-5.,0.,5.,0.}, QLineF{0.,-5.,0.,5.}};
        for (auto l : center) {
            auto c = new QGraphicsLineItem{l, &m_center};
            c->setFlags(QGraphicsItem::ItemIgnoresTransformations);
            c->setPen(pen);
        }
        for (auto range = 10.; range < 101.; range += 10.) {
            auto circle = new QGraphicsEllipseItem(0.-range, 0.-range, 2.*range, 2.*range, &m_macroGraticule);
            circle->setPen(pen);
        }
        pen = QPen{Qt::white, 1, Qt::DashLine};
        pen.setCosmetic(true);
        for (auto range = 2.5; range < 9.9; range += 2.5) {
            auto circle = new QGraphicsEllipseItem(0.-range, 0.-range, 2.*range, 2.*range, &m_microGraticule);
            circle->setPen(pen);
        }
    }
};
```

The mapping between the scene units and the view is maintained as follows:

1. Each time the view range is changed (from e.g. the combo box), the `QGraphicsView::fitInView` method is called with a rectangle in scene units (of nautical miles). This takes care of **all of the scaling, centering, etc.**. E.g. to select a range of 10NM, we'd call `view.fitInView(QRect{-10.,-10.,20.,20.), Qt::KeepAspectRatio)`
2. The graticule(s) can be disabled/enabled as appropriate for a given range to unclutter the view.

   ```
   int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
       QApplication app{argc, argv};
       SceneManager mgr;
       mgr.newTargets();

       QWidget w;
       QGridLayout layout{&w};
       QGraphicsView view;
       QComboBox combo;
       QPushButton newTargets{"New Targets"};
       layout.addWidget(&view, 0, 0, 1, 2);
       layout.addWidget(&combo, 1, 0);
       layout.addWidget(&newTargets, 1, 1);

       view.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
       view.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
       view.setBackgroundBrush(Qt::black);
       view.setScene(mgr.scene());
       view.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
       mgr.monitor(&view);

       combo.addItems({"10", "25", "50", "100"});
       auto const recenterView = [&]{
           auto range = combo.currentText().toDouble();
           view.fitInView(-range, -range, 2.*range, 2.*range, Qt::KeepAspectRatio);
           mgr.setMicroGraticuleVisible(range <= 20.);
       };
       QObject::connect(&combo, &QComboBox::currentTextChanged, recenterView);
       QObject::connect(&mgr, &SceneManager::viewResized, recenterView);
       QObject::connect(&newTargets, &QPushButton::clicked, [&]{ mgr.newTargets(); });
       w.show();
       return app.exec();
   }

   #include "main.moc"
   ```

Answer (score 1):

So as Kuba suggested, I was overcomplicating this a bit. With his help this is what ended up getting me the result I needed. Not 100% sure on some of it, but for now it's working the way I need it to.

```
view = ui->GraphicsView;
scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
int baseSize = 1000; // MAGIC value that works, anything other than this, not so much
view->setSceneRect(0,0,baseSize,baseSize);
baseViewSize = view->sceneRect().width();
view->setScene(scene);
```

My drawPoint method works fine, no changes were needed.

Finally, here is my slider

```
void MainWindow:: on_PlotSlider_sliderMoved(int position){
    const qreal factor = 1.01;
    viewScaleValue = qPow(factor, -position);//-position to invert the scale
    QMatrix matrix;
     // below is the update, again 6 is a MAGIC number, no clue why 6 works...
    matrix.scale((baseViewSize/6 / position, baseViewSize/6 / position);
    view->setMatrix(matrix);
```

}

While my problem is solved, I would love some explanation as to my 2 MAGIC numbers.

Why does it all only work is the baseSize is 1000?

Why does it only scale correctly if I divide the BaseViewSize by 6?

Comment: It's hard to tell how it works because we have no idea what the position is, what units you use in your scene, etc. Other bits of your code are missing. There's no point to setting the scene rectangle - the scene does it already and does it correctly. Say you want to fit the 10NM range around the origin in scene coordinates - it's an area 20NM wide/tall and starting at -10NM,-10NM. All you need to do is call `view->fitInView(-10.,-10.,20.,20.)`. That's it. The view takes care of figuring out what scaling to set. You need to invoke this every time the view changes size, of course.